# Focus event triggers input event in IE vs modern browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, events, input, focus

How to prevent input event firing after focus/set Selection Range event in IE? Code example here:

```
var setSelectionRange = function (input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    }
    else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
        range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
        range.select();
    }
};
```

Comment: Which version of IE is causing troubles? Your code [doesn't seem to fire oninput](http://jsfiddle.net/r7pzyyey/)  in IE11. A [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help too.

Comment: the common design pattern for selection on focus is
<input type="text" name="textbox" onfocus="this.select()"/>

Comment: 1. All versions IE.
2. In the template html I also have placeholder for the input.
<input type="search" class="form-control" id="myId" placeholder="Search...">

Comment: See [**my explanation with very short solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060030/9801830) for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

After long research, I've decided to change functionality. There's condition for input string. If it's not empty than focus and set Caret Position. Now the input event fires only the input text is not empty. It's cross browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this question. I switched to use the "keydown" event instead of the "input" event in the addEventListener method.

Comment: See [**my explanation with very short solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060030/9801830) for your issue.