# IE 10, 11. How to prevent the triggering of input events on focus from text input with placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, internet-explorer-11, placeholder

In IE 11 if I have an empty email `input` with a `placeholder`, then on clicking (focusing) it, the `input` event is being triggered.

Does anyone know why and is there a solution to this, since the `input` value hasn't really changed?

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myEmail');
el.addEventListener("input", myFunction, true);
function myFunction()
{
    alert("changed");
}
```

```html
<input id="myEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">
```

Comment: See [**my explanation with very short solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060030/9801830) and set my answer as accepted please – so could all users have profit from my correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came very late to the party, but I had the same problem, and I came to a workaround  to fix this behavior on IE.
In fact, there's two different bugs (or rather, only one bug but with two behavior depending on whether the target is an input or a textarea).

- For `input` : the event is triggered each time the visual content of the field change, including keyboard inputting (naturally), but also when a placeholder appears/disappears (blur when no content), or when a visible placeholder is changed programmatically.
- For `textarea`: it's basically the same, exepts that the event don't trigger when the placeholder disapears.

```js
function onInputWraper(cb) {
    if (!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE|Trident/)) return cb;


    return function (e) {
        var t = e.target,
            active = (t == document.activeElement);
        if (!active || (t.placeholder && t.composition_started !== true)) {
            t.composition_started = active;
            if ((!active && t.tagName == 'TEXTAREA') || t.tagName == 'INPUT') {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
        cb(e);
    };
}

var el = document.getElementById('myEmail');
el.addEventListener("input", onInputWraper(myFunction), true);
function myFunction() {
    alert("changed");
}
```

```html
<input id="myEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">
```

And there's a full-working example, where you can also change placeholders value

```js
function onInputWraper(cb) {
  if (!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE|Trident/)) return cb;


  return function (e) {
    var t = e.target,
        active = (t == document.activeElement);
    if (!active || (t.placeholder && t.composition_started !== true)) {
      t.composition_started = active;
      if ((!active && t.tagName == 'TEXTAREA') || t.tagName == 'INPUT') {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
    cb(e);
  };
}

function handle(event) {
  console.log('EVENT', event);
  document.getElementById('output')
    .insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "<p>" + event.type + " triggered on " + event.target.tagName +
                        '</p>');
}

var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

input.addEventListener('input', onInputWraper(handle));
textarea.addEventListener('input', onInputWraper(handle));
// input.addEventListener('input', handle);
// textarea.addEventListener('input', handle);

// Example's settings

function removeListeners(elem) {
  var value = elem.value,
      clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
  elem.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, elem);
  clone.value = value;
  return clone;
}

document.querySelector('#settings input[type="checkbox"]').addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    document.getElementById('output').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>Filter enabled !</p>');

    //input = removeListeners(input);

    console.log(input.value.length, (input == document.activeElement));

    input = removeListeners(input);
    input.addEventListener('input', onInputWraper(handle));
    input.composing = input.value.length > 0 || (input == document.activeElement);

    textarea = removeListeners(textarea);
    textarea.addEventListener('input', onInputWraper(handle));
    textarea.composing = textarea.value.length > 0 || (textarea == document.activeElement);

  } else {
    document.getElementById('output').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>Filter disabled !</p>');

    input = removeListeners(input);
    input.addEventListener('input', handle);
    input.composing = void 0;

    textarea = removeListeners(textarea);
    textarea.addEventListener('input', handle);
    textarea.composing = void 0;

  }
});

document.getElementById('input_cfg').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('input').setAttribute('placeholder', document.getElementById(
    'input_placeholder').value);
});
document.getElementById('textarea_cfg').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('textarea').setAttribute('placeholder', document.getElementById(
    'textarea_placeholder').value);
});
```

```css
* {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
}

dd {
  background: FloralWhite;
  margin: 0;
}

dt {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: steelblue;
  color: AntiqueWhite;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

button,
label {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  color: DarkSlateGray;
}

#settings label {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px;
}

#forms input,
#forms textarea,
#settings input:not([type]) {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 340px);
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 320px;
  min-height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
  cursor: text;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: LightBlue;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: LightBlue;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: LightBlue;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Forms</dt>
  <dd id="forms">
    <label for="input">Input: </label>
    <input id="input" name="input" class="testing" placeholder="Type some text" />
    <label for="texarea">Textarea: </label>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" placeholder="Type some text"></textarea>
  </dd>
  <dt>Settings</dt>
  <dd id="settings">
    <p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" checked>Enable filtering script</label>
      <button id="input_cfg">Change input's placeholder to</button><input id="input_placeholder" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="textarea_cfg">Change textarea's placeholder to</button>
      <input id="textarea_placeholder" />
    </p>
  </dd>
  <dt>Output</dt>
  <dd id="output"></dd>
</dl>
```

[or on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Calak/4nko8m7c/)

Comment: This works. Thanks for the solution and the explaination

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bug. `oninput` has been supported since IE9 should only fire when the value is changed. An alternate approach would be to use `onkeyup`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

If you want to handle input and validation you can just add a second eventlistener (assuming your html is the same as above).

```
var el = document.getElementById('myEmail');
function myFunction() {
  console.log("changed");
}
el.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction, true);
function validation() {
  console.log("validated");
}
el.addEventListener("keyup", validation, true);
```

Comment: Hmm. Cant take that approach as I am using a validation library which relies on input event. The validation is supposed to happen on input event but in IE 11 its happening on focus

Comment: What about the onchange event?

Comment: onchange only triggers once focused out. I need 'input' event since the validation needs to happen as you type

Comment: Why not just add multiple eventlisteners onkeyup. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### The solution is very short!

At first we don't need so much of code what we can see in accepted answer. At second you have to understand why it is happening:

1. Fake `oninput` event triggers only on inputs with a `placeholder` on getting a focus and only if the input value is empty. It happens because bad developer from IE had thought that the input value changes from `placeholder value` to real `value`, but it is misunderstanding from this bad developer from IE.
2. An `input` without placeholders doesn't have this problems.

The first solution is very simple: do not use a `placeholder` if you do not really need it. In most cases you can add a `title` to the element instead of a `placeholder`. You could also write your `placeholder` text before, below or above the `input`.

### If you have to use a `placeholder`

The second solution is also very simple and short: save the previous `value` on the `input` object and compare it with a new `value` – if it was not changed then `return` from the function before your code.

### Life examples

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=search]');
input.addEventListener('input', function(e)
{
    if(this.prevVal == this.value /* if the value was not changed */
        || !this.prevVal && '' == this.value) //only for the first time because we do not know the previous value
        return; //the function returns "undefined" as value in this case

    this.prevVal = this.value;

    //YOUR CODE PLACE

    console.log('log: ' + this.value)

}, false);
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
```

**Or if you use it as inline JavaScript:**

```js
function onSearch(trg)
{
    if(trg.prevVal == trg.value /* if the value was not changed */
        || !trg.prevVal && '' == trg.value) //only for the first time because we do not know the previous value
        return; //the function returns "undefined" as value in this case

    trg.prevVal = trg.value; // save the previous value on input object

    //YOUR CODE PLACE

    console.log('log: ' + trg.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="Search..." oninput="onSearch(this)"/>
```