# Vue - @input is triggered by :placeholder in Internet Explorer 11 immediately upon page load not when entering a value

Tags: vue.js

Vue - @input is triggered by :placeholder in Internet Explorer 11 immediately upon page load not when entering a value. That is, the problem is only in the explorer. When the page loads, input is triggered immediately, but only if there is a placeholder

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Тег SCRIPT</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body> 
 <div id="app">
   <component-c/>
 </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 var ComponentA = Vue.component('ComponentA', {
   props: ['field'],
   methods: {
  //@input is triggered by :placeholder in Interner Exployer 11 immediately upon page load not when entering a value
  validator: function (ev){
   console.log(ev.target.value, 'value in validator');
  }
   },
   computed: {
        fieldPlaceholder: function () {
            return this.field.placeholder;
  },
    },
  template: '<input type="password" @input="validator" :placeholder = "fieldPlaceholder">'
 });
 
 var ComponentС = Vue.component('ComponentB', {
  data: function () {
     return {
     field: {
       placeholder: 'place'
     }
   }
  },
    components: {
  'component-a': ComponentA,
    },
    template: '<component-a :field = "this.field" />'
 })
  
 var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
    components: {
  'component-c': ComponentС,
    }
 })
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you would like to target internet explorer 11, you must activate babel polyfill in the build of your application. more detail here. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist

Comment: Please check: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7138 and [IE 11 text input with placeholder triggering 'input' event on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48138865)

Comment: I have a laravel project. How can I embed a polyfil in it? https://gitlab.com/Kir1/arenda.git

branch placeholder

Comment: I have a laravel project. How can I embed a polyfil in it?
 https://gitlab.com/Kir1/arenda.git

branch placeholder  

I use
https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/polyfill

But error concat function

ERROR in ./resources/js/mixins/forms/solofield/fieldContainer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.concat' in 'D:\OSLast\OSPanel\domains\arenda.git\resources\js\mixins\forms\solofield'

Comment: I install laravel-mix-polyfill and core-js, but my problem did not dare http://SSMaker.ru/15d1d557/

Comment: I found out that it turns out that the problem pops up exactly when Cyrillic characters get into the placeholder. With numbers and Latin, this is not